# Converting JSON values to an array

Tags: javascript, json, socket.io, leaflet

I working with leaflet maps and html5 geolocation.  I have a view that receives coords from a node.js server and adds markers for each unique id and updates their positions as new coords come in.  I'm storing the marker objects in an object, the IDs as the keys, the markers as the values.  So the `markers` object looks like this when tracking two devices:

```
Object {qwpW9K0L1OtOhsV3CF0G: e, syeQs_oH7s8z8f0UCF0I: e}
```

Where the e is an actual marker.

The problem I'm working on is that the leaflet api likes to receive arrays of data.  For example, I'd like to fit the map view bounds to the markers using a feature group and `map.fitBounds(...)`.  So i'm iterating through the object and pushing the markers into a new array and updating the map bounds every time a new marker is created or new coords come in and it seems extremely inefficient and just plain the wrong way to do it.

Complete socket.io code block I'm working on:

```
socket.on('markerCoords', function(data) {
    var markerGroup = [];
    if(data.id in markers) {
        markers[data.id].setLatLng([data.data.latitude, data.data.longitude]);
        $.each(markers, function(i, e) {
            markerGroup.push(e);
        });
        var group = new L.featureGroup(markerGroup);
        map.fitBounds(group.getBounds().pad(0.5));
    } else {
        var marker = L.marker([data.data.latitude, data.data.longitude], {"title": data.id, "draggable": true}).addTo(map);
        markers[data.id] = marker;
        $.each(markers, function(i, e) {
            markerGroup.push(e);
        });
        var group = new L.featureGroup(markerGroup);
        map.fitBounds(group.getBounds().pad(1.0));
   }
});
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like one possible solution is to simply create the feature group only once and updated it when necessary:

```
var group = new L.featureGroup();

socket.on('markerCoords', function(data) {
    var markerGroup = [];
    if(data.id in markers) {
        markers[data.id].setLatLng([data.data.latitude, data.data.longitude]);
        map.fitBounds(group.getBounds().pad(0.5));
    } else {
        markers[data.id] = L.marker(
            [data.data.latitude, data.data.longitude],
            {"title": data.id, "draggable": true}
        ).addTo(map);

        group.addLayer(markers[data.id]);
        map.fitBounds(group.getBounds().pad(1.0));
    }
});
```

You could probably also just add the group to the map once on startup, not every marker individually.

Comment: Just made your edits and its working smooth.  Code looks much cleaner and should probably run better with many users.  Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome! I assume that `getBounds` will still use most of the runtime, so that wouldn't change, but at least you are not creating a new array and group every time, which would have gotten slower each time.